# Stacking 3 elements both sides on window resize with CSS using inline, flex, float or whatever

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float, css-grid

I know there are many questions about this, the most of them says this is not possible because they ask about 1 method only, this question is about any method, I simply can't believe this is not possible with CSS.

I have 3 elements, 2 of them are stacked on the left and the other one is taller and his width fills the remaining space, when the screen goes smaller they stack, so the right element moves between first and last element:

[image]

I tried different methods like `display:inline-block`, `float:left` (and right), `display:flex` (and some flex properties) and even tables! I can not achieve it.

These are my 3 best attempts:

```css
.test_inline div{display:inline-block;}
.test_inline .right{flex-grow:1; width: calc(100% - 130px);min-width:100px;}

.test_flex{display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap}
.test_flex .right{flex-grow:1; width: calc(100% - 130px);min-width:100px;}

.test_float .left{float:left;}
.test_float .right{display: flow-root;}

/* */

.main{ margin: 50px; }
div div{ border: 1px solid #333; }
.left{ width: 100px; }
.right{ height: 50px; }
```

```html
<div class='main test_inline'>
  <div class='left'>1 Top left</div>
  <div class='right'>2 Right</div>
  <div class='left'>3 Bottom Left</div>
</div>
<div class='main test_flex'>
  <div class='left'>1 Top left</div>
  <div class='right'>2 Right</div>
  <div class='left'>3 Bottom Left</div>
</div>
<div class='main test_float'>
  <div class='left'>1 Top left</div>
  <div class='right'>2 Right</div>
  <div class='left'>3 Bottom Left</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I simply can't believe this is not possible with CSS.

It is possible. In fact, it's fairly simple with CSS Grid.

No need for floats, inline block, absolute positioning or even flex.

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4xewn7a8/)

```css
.test_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.right {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

@media ( max-width: 600px) {
  .test_grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  }
}

/* */

.main {
  margin: 50px;
}

div div {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class='main test_grid'>
  <div class='left'>1 Top left</div>
  <div class='right'>2 Right</div>
  <div class='left'>3 Bottom Left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both answers works for me, I choose this one as answer because it's very simple, I didn't know about css grid, it's time to learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways you can go about it @stamin. Ultimately I think you would need to know which side of the markup you want to determine the height of your UI though.

This positions the right element absolutely and uses flexbox for the left two. You could always do it the other way.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item one">Top Left</div>
  <div class="item two">Right</div>
  <div class="item three">Bottom Left</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.one,
.three {
  text-align: left;
}
.two {
text-align: right;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-right: 50%;
  }
  .one,
  .three {
    float: left;
  }
  .two {
    align-self: stretch;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

And here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/css-reorder